# how do set default value of config in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, configuration

i have  file  etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="productquestion" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Productquestion Configuration</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <resource>Mageaddons_Productquestion::config_module</resource>
            <group id="productquestion_admin" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Product Question</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="guest_question" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="15" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Allow Guest Ask Question</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="guest_answer" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Allow Guest Answer Question</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="productquestion_frontend" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Frontend Setting</label>
                <field id="product_question_per_page" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Product Question per Page to display</label>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_by" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Default questions sort by</label>
                    <source_model>Mageaddons\Productquestion\Model\Config\Source\Sortby</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="sort_dierction" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="3" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Default questions sort direction</label>
                    <source_model>Mageaddons\Productquestion\Model\Config\Source\Sortdirection</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

and etc/config.xml

```
`<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <productquestion>
            <productquestion_admin>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <guest_question>1</guest_question>
                <guest_answer>1</guest_answer>
            </productquestion_admin>
        </productquestion>      
    </default>
</config>`
```

it **not set** default value.

what wrong for file config.xml? thanks

Comment: `ect` should be `etc`. Is this a typo? or that's how your folder is named?

Comment: yes it must be etc. i editted question.

Comment: are the backticks in config.xml actually there or is a mistake from posting the code here?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the PHP error

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xA9 0x20 0x32 0x30 in Entity, line: 4

It sounds like one of your files has an encoding error.  Step one will be identifying which file this is.  Removing `config.xml` and `system.xml` one by one, clearing cache, and then re-adding each back (again,clearing the cache between each step) should reveal which file is the problem file.  Once you've got that identified you can investigate **why** your text editor's encoding is set incorrectly.

**Update**

It looks like your `config.xml` is incorrect.  The following

```
<default>
    <productquestion>
        <productquestion>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
            <guest_question>1</guest_question>
            <guest_answer>1</guest_answer>
        </productquestion>
    </productquestion>      
</default>
```

will set the default for configuration paths of

```
productquestion/productquestion/enabled
productquestion/productquestion/guest_question
productquestion/productquestion/guest_answer
```

However, your `system.xml` sets up a configuration section named `productquestion`, two groups named `productquestion_admin` and `productquestion_frontend`, meaning your final field paths are

```
productquestion/productquestion_frontend/enabled
productquestion/productquestion_frontend/guest_question
productquestion/productquestion_frontend/guest_answer

productquestion/productquestion_admin/product_question_per_page
productquestion/productquestion_admin/sort_by
productquestion/productquestion_admin/sort_dierction
```

So, if you wanted to setup a `config.xml` file that set a default value for `productquestion/productquestion_frontend/enabled`, you'd do

```
<default>
    <productquestion>
        <productquestion_frontend>
            <enabled>1</enabled>
        </productquestion_frontend>
    </productquestion>      
</default>
```

Also, don't forget to check if `core_config_data` has values already.  Even if you don't explicitly change a configuration value, saving a group will save the defaults into the database, and further changes to `config.xml` fill have no effect.

Comment: i made it and get error same. when i remove `config.xml` it work. after  re-adding `config.xml` get error. what wrong for file config.xml?

Comment: i removed `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->`  and re-run it run but not set default value. You Can help?

Comment: @xanka question updated.  Don't forget to vote on answers that help you -- a good voting/accepting ratio can help get your answers in the future.